# How can I remove a secondary IP address?

Tags: networking, server

I'm running Ubuntu Server 17.04. All packages are up to date.

The contents of my `/etc/network/interfaces` is as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 10.99.0.10
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 10.99.0.1
```

But if I run `ip addr` I see a secondary address:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:98:35:c1:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.99.0.10/16 brd 10.99.255.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.99.1.31/16 brd 10.99.255.255 scope global secondary enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2a0:98ff:fe35:c1cd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

There are no files or folders in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`. How can I permanently remove the secondary IP address? It reappears after every reboot.

Comment: I'm reading this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/where-does-my-secondary-ip-come-from where it is suggested that you delete the secondary address *while the dhcpcd service is stopped*; and that you may have an additional `dhcp@network` in `/etc/systemd/system` that you can do without.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that even though dhcp was not enabled in `/etc/network/interfaces`, `dhcpcd.service` was still running and assigning an IP. I fixed this with

```
systemctl stop dhcpcd
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

and rebooted. Secondary IP gone!

Answer (score 3):

In case you set static IP on eth0 (or wlan0) at file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` like;

```
interface eth0
    static ip_address=192.168.3.51
    static routers=192.168.3.1
    static domain_name_servers=168.126.63.1
```

then you go to `/etc/network/interfaces` and check if you set your eth0 (or wlan0) as dhcp as:

```
iface eth0 dhcp
```

then you change it to

```
iface eth0 manual
```

This will fix it.

Comment: should it be manual or static?